# Store current view in cookie

Tags: javascript, three.js

We are using three.js to show 3D slices of stomach contents from MRI measurements. Colors are approximate concentrations; each bubble is a voxel, i.e. a 3D pixel. Use menu at the left to load.

http://menne-biomed.de/uni/3d/

(Can use that as sample code)

The flat surface at the top (rotate the image) is the liquid level of the meal from gravity.

We would like to store the current view in a cookie, so that the user get the same perspective after coming back. However, I could not make out which matrix to store in a cookie.

I have read
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1188#issuecomment-3666286

but I could not find out which matrix to store in the cookie. Those I found do not change on rotation. 
Note that I know how to use cookies, so this is a THREE.js question, not one related to generic javascript programming.

Comment: Cookies are limited to 4K bytes. Not a very good storage medium.

Comment: Did you count how many byte as 4*4 matrix, rounded to 3 digit, needs?

Comment: < 900 bytes, with delimiters. You could serialize some JSON and store it as a cookie.

Comment: what about using localstorage ? you need to serialize whatever data you are using in a string , should not be a big deal if you are able to use WebGL.

Comment: Using the cookie is not the problem: finding what to store is. I have edited the question. Localstorage would be fine too, but my question relates to the matrix to use, not the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only the camera coordinates you want to save you could do this:

```js
var string = JSON.stringify( [
    camera.position.x,
    camera.position.y,
    camera.position.z,
    camera.rotation.x,
    camera.rotation.y,
    camera.rotation.z
] );
```

And then for setting up the camera from the data saved:

```js
var array = JSON.parse( string );
camera.position.x = array[ 0 ];
camera.position.y = array[ 1 ];
camera.position.z = array[ 2 ];
camera.rotation.x = array[ 3 ];
camera.rotation.y = array[ 4 ];
camera.rotation.z = array[ 5 ];
```

Comment: That's why I asked; I had already tried this, but the problem is that these values are always 0. Tried with console.log(camera.rotation.x,camera.rotation.y, ..., in animate).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realised you tried this already. This should work though, you must be doing something wrong, and with the information you shared I can't guess what can be.

Comment: You are right. I had forgotten to correctly update the trackball camera, and it came in the way.